# Using ES6 modules with WebPack, why require still needed

Tags: javascript, require, reactjs, webpack

In the code sample below, why does the commented line not work to import marked? I'm using the https://github.com/shama/es6-loader

```
module $ from 'jquery';
module React from 'react';

//import { marked } from 'marked';
var marked = require("marked");
```

Here's a sample repository: https://github.com/justin808/react-tutorial-hot/tree/es6

This demo shows:
1. Webpack and hot-reload
2. React
3. ES6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use ES6 in webpack.config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the [destructuring operator](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-destructuring-assignment.html) which won't work if there is nothing to destructure, i.e. `marked` exports a function.

`import marked from 'marked'` should work though.

Comment: That makes sense! I didn't try it yet. Any advantages to skipping "require"?

Answer (score 0):

The es6-loader uses the [es6-module-transpiler](https://www.npmjs.org/package/es6-module-transpiler) which states that

> The ES6 module syntax is still undergoing a lot of churn, and will likely change before final approval.

Maybe the described syntax is not supported yet?