# How can I use ES6 in webpack.config.js?

Tags: webpack

How to use ES6 in webpack.config ?
Like this repo 
https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit
does ?

For instance:

using this

```javascript
import webpack from 'webpack';
```

instead of

```javascript
var webpack = require('webpack');
```

It is quite a curiosity rather than a need.

Comment: The question is how to use es6 in webpack.config.It seems clear to me.I update my question with an example.

Comment: The file gets parsed by node.js, which doesn't support es6 by default. There are command line flags to turn this on, but I don't know what they are. You might also try using io.js instead of node

Comment: Same problem here. It's extremely confusing because webpack itself DOES support ES6 module syntax! But in webpack.config you still have to use `require`. It seems overkill to install `babel` JUST for the webpack config file!

Comment: Webpack documentation says https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#es6-recommended- ES6 syntax can be used without need of babel. 

Did anyone succeed using ES6 syntax import without using babel?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Try naming your config as `webpack.config.babel.js`. You should have [babel-register](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-register) included in the project. Example at [react-router-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap).

Webpack relies on [interpret](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interpret) internally to make this work.

Comment: This worked for me. I `npm run` this script: `webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js`.

Comment: I think it might be able to pick it up directly even without `--config`.

Comment: @bebraw are you sure the required package is `babel` and not `babel-core`? I can get it to work with just the latter but not *just* the former. I'm confused by this, however, because `babel` depends on `babel-core`. Should work with either standalone.

Comment: I think it should be added that the `babel-loader` module is also required

Comment: I think this may not work as expected when using webpack 1.12.x with babel 6. That version of webpack relies on an old version of interpret (6.4) which does not know about the new babel 6 register modules. Either downgrade babel 6, hack webpack to use the new interpret version (1.0), or upgrade webpack to an unstable dev version.

Comment: Actually, it works fine, just need to set your babel presets in a .babelrc file.

Comment: I used this specific preset to get this to work: `echo '{ "presets": ["es2015"] }' > .babelrc`

Comment: @skymk Reading from the [source](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/bc29455e92f4b760db745775a4fca5cde0d01d23/bin/convert-argv.js#L33) I would say yes. It still relies on [interpret](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interpret).

Comment: this is too good to be true.

I still cannot understand who is picking up the file webpack.config.babel.js instead of webpack.config.js.

Who is telling webpack command line to pick up that file instead?

Comment: +Ghassan Karwchan. It's [interpret](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interpret). You can find the other supported formats there as well.

Comment: @GhassanKarwchan I looked a bit into this, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46276592/444255)

Comment: This cured my OCD. Thank you! using requires in the webpack config where every other file is importing made me squirm every time.

Comment: Webpack will find `webpack.config.babel.js` without you explicitly passing config filename via command line options. `babel-loader` is not needed for `webpack.config.babel.js` to be successfully processed. For it to work you basically need to rename `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.babel.js` and one of [these three packages](https://github.com/js-cli/js-interpret/blob/v1.0.4/index.js#L2-L29). More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47242644/52499).

Comment: ...Depending on your node version and what features you're going to use you might need `.babelrc` with list of plugins/presets. For `.babelrc` to not be in the way of your project code, you might consider looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556951/52499)

Comment: Running with webpack 4, I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`, whereever I did `import x from 'y'`. So I will assume this solution does not work with webpack 4?

Comment: @smac89 Can you link to your project? How did you configure Babel? It crashes like that if you disabled module transformation.

Comment: I finally got it working. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51774289/2089675

Answer (score 45):

As an alternative to what @bebraw suggests, you can create a JavaScript automation script with ES6+ syntax:

```js
// tools/bundle.js

import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.js'; // <-- Contains ES6+

const bundler = webpack(webpackConfig);

bundler.run(...);
```

And execute it with babel:

```
$ babel-node tools/bundle
```

**P.S.**: Calling webpack via JavaScript API might be a better approach (than by calling it via a command line) when you need to implement more complex build steps. E.g. after server-side bundle is ready, startup Node.js app server, and right after Node.js server is started, launch BrowserSync dev server.

#### See also:

- [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) (`package.json/scripts`, `tools/bundle.js`, `tools/webpack.config.js`)
- [React Static Boilerplate](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate) (`run.js`, `webpack.config.js`, `node run`)
- [You might not need Gulp.js](https://medium.com/swlh/you-might-not-need-gulp-js-89a0220487dd)

Comment: Although a little complex, this is exactly what react-starter-kit uses. It should be the best answer.

Answer (score 20):

Another approach is to have a npm script like this: `"webpack": "babel-node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack"`, and run it like so: `npm run webpack`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when passing a custom config to webpack

`babel-node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config custom-webpack.config`

Answer (score 17):

This is what worked for me using webpack 4:

In `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env APP_ENV=dev webpack-serve --require @babel/register"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2"
},

"babel": {
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
  ]
}
```

You can clearly see how each dependency is used, so no surprises there.

*Note I am using [`webpack-serve`--require](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-serve), but if you want to use the `webpack` command instead, replace it with `webpack --config-register`. In either case, `@babel/register` is needed to make this work.*

And that's it!

`yarn dev`

And you are able to use `es6` in the config!

---

For `webpack-dev-server`, use the `--config-register` option which is the same as with the `webpack` command

---

#### NOTE:

**NO need to rename the config file to `webpack.config.babel.js` (as suggested by the accepted answer). `webpack.config.js` will work just fine.**

Comment: Looks like web-serve is deprecated. Any idea of how to make this work with webpack-dev-server? I'm not seeing a --require option for it in the docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver

Comment: @CrhistianRamirez, use the `--config-register` option. Also the repo for `webpack-serve` moved here: https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-serve

Comment: Cool! that worked for me. Here's what my script looks like: `webpack --config-register @babel/register --config webpack/development.config.js` I had to specificy --config because my webpack config is in a folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

For readers in 2024 who are also using `tsconfig.json` with the newest TSConfig option `"moduleResolution": "bundler"`:

1. Remove `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. (see the [issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/guides/choosing-compiler-options.html#im-using-a-bundler))
2. Rename `webpack.config.js` into `webpack.config.mjs` (confirmed with the maintainer of webpack 2024/3/7)
3. Enjoy.

---

For readers in 2022:

```
"webpack": "^5.70.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
```

1. Add `"type": "module"` in `package.json`
2. Change the syntax of your `webpack.config.js` to ESM.
3. Enjoy.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you ended up with for step 2?

Answer (score 15):

I had a problem getting @Juho's solution running with Webpack 2. The [Webpack migration docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#mixing-es2015-with-amd-and-commonjs) suggest you to turn of babel module parsing:

> It is important to note that you will want to tell Babel to not parse
>   these module symbols so webpack can use them. You can do this by
>   setting the following in your .babelrc or babel-loader options.
>
> .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
         ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
    ]
}
```

Sadly, this conflicts with the automatic babel register functionality. Removing

```
{ "modules": false }
```

from the babel config got things running again. However, this would result in breaking tree-shaking, so a complete solution would involve [overwriting the presets in the loader options](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1403#issuecomment-244814526):

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: path.resolve('src'),
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                babelrc: false,
                presets: [['env', {modules: false}]]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Edit**, 13th Nov 2017; updated webpack config snippet to Webpack 3 (thanks to @x-yuri). Old, Webpack 2 snippet:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: ['node_modules'],
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [
            ['es2015', { modules: false }],
        ],
    },
},
```

Comment: [These days](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) (Webpack 3), it would probably look like this: `module:{rules: [{test: /\.js$/, include: path.resolve('src'), loader: 'babel-loader', options: {babelrc: false, presets: [['env', {modules: false}]]}}]}` ([gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/46801063e7a8a27c8eb745adf39af725)). `-loader` suffix no longer optional. Try to avoid `exclude` and prefer `include`. Strings in include/exclude [work](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v3.8.1/lib/RuleSet.js#L300) only if absolute paths. `query` was renamed to `options`.

Comment: Also, make it clear please that you don't want `{modules: false}` in `.babelrc` to be able to use `import`'s in `webpack.config.babel.js`.

Comment: For Webpack 4  `-loader` suffix needs to be added back https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed

Answer (score 13):

This is really easy, but it wasn't obvious to me from any of the answers, so if anyone else is confused like me:

**Just append `.babel` to the part of your filename before the extension** (assuming that you have `babel-register` installed as a dependency).

Example:

```
mv webpack.config.js webpack.config.babel.js
```

Comment: I don't use babel because webpack itself already supports ES6 module syntax, and my project doesn't need to be compatible with ES5. It's just the config file that still needs `require`. That's weird isn't it?

Comment: Woah that’s interesting! I didn’t know that. I’ll need to revisit this. Weird that the configs file still requires require

Answer (score 8):

For **TypeScript**: straight from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/

```
npm install --save-dev typescript ts-node @types/node @types/webpack
# and, if using webpack-dev-server
npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-dev-server
```

then proceed to write your, e.g.:
**webpack.config.ts**

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './foo.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'foo.bundle.js'
  }
};

export default config;
```

Check the link for more details where you can use a plugin to have a separate tsconfig file just for the webpack config if you're not targeting commonjs (which is a req for this to work since it relies on ts-node).

Comment: Thanks for this, couldn't get modules working for webpack.config.js but happy to use TypeScript instead which does work.

Answer (score 7):

Configuration for **Babel 7** & **Webpack 4**

*package.json*

```
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --env.dev",
        "build": "webpack --env.prod",
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
        ...
        "webpack": "^4.17.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack-config-utils": "^2.3.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

*webpack.config.babel.js*

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import { resolve } from 'path';

import { getIfUtils, removeEmpty } from 'webpack-config-utils';

export default env => {
    const { ifProd, ifNotProd } = getIfUtils(env);

    return {
        mode: ifProd('production', 'development'),
        devtool: ifNotProd('cheap-module-source-map'),
        output: {
            path: resolve(__dirname, ifProd('prod', 'dev')),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
```

Comment: This _still_ does not work for me, but IMHO looks to be the most up-to-date and almost cleanest example (class properties related entries are superfluous for the task at hand).

Answer (score 5):

One more way is to use require argument for node:

`node -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack`

Found this way in [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json), look at `build-main` and `build-renderer` scripts.

Comment: Spectacular - was just looking at Electron and starting up a separate server, your answer helped perfectly! :)

Answer (score 3):

Rename `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.babel.js`.

Then in .babelrc: `{"presets": ["es2015"]}`

However, if you want to use a different babel config for babel-cli, your .babelrc might look something like this:

```
{
  "env": {
    "babel-cli": {
      "presets": [["es2015", {"modules": false}]]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": ["es2015"]
    },
    "development": {
      "presets": ["es2015"]
    }
  }
}
```

And in package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "BABEL_ENV='babel-cli' babel src -d dist/babel --source-maps",
    "build-dev": "NODE_ENV='development' webpack -d --progress --profile --colors",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

It's dumb but the `{"modules": false}` will break webpack if you don't use different envs.

For more info about .babelrc, check the [official docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but I wanted to add for any TypeScript users out there a similar solution to @Sandrik above

I have two scripts that I use pointing to webpack configs (JS files) that contain ES6 syntax.

`"start-dev": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config ./webpack/webpack.config.dev.js"`

and

`"build": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.config.js"`

Answer (score 2):

### Using Webpack 4 and Babel 7

To setup a webpack configuration file to use ES2015 requires Babel:

Install dev dependencies:

```sh
npm i -D  webpack \
          webpack-cli \
          webpack-dev-server \
          @babel/core \
          @babel/register \
          @babel/preset-env
npm i -D  html-webpack-plugin
```

Create a `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Create your webpack config, `webpack.config.babel.js`:

```js
import { resolve as _resolve } from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

const config = {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [_resolve(__dirname, './src'), 'node_modules']
  }
};

export default config;
```

Create your scripts in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
```

Run `npm run build` and `npm start`.

The webpack config is based on a sample project with the following directory structure:

```sh
├── README.md
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── Greeter.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.babel.js
```

Sample project: [Webpack Configuration Language Using Babel](https://github.com/stormwild/webpack-babel)

Answer (score 1):

My Best approach along with npm  script is

```
node -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack
```

and configure rest of scripts as per your requirement for [Babel](https://github.com/babel/)

Answer (score 1):

After tons of the documents...

1. Just install es2015 preset (not env !!!) and add it to

   ```
   .babelrc:
   {
       "presets": [
            ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Rename your `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.babel.js`

Answer (score 0):

Adding es6 to webpack is a 3 step process

1. In **webpack.config.js** add

   ```
   module:{

             rules:[
               {
                 test: /\.js$/,
                 loader: 'babel-loader'
               }
             ]
          }
   ```

   2. Create a **.babel.rc** and add inside it

> ```
> {
>     "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
>     "plugins": [
>         [
>           "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
>         ]
>       ]
> }
> ```

3. in **package.json** add

> ```
> npm install @babel/core --save-dev
> npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
> npm install @babel/preset-react --save-dev
> npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --save-dev
> npm install babel-loader --save-dev
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue, resolved it by installing lastest webpack, webpack-cli and webpack-devserver see example [here](https://gist.github.com/charleslukes/81750f595d29ec4e751cde21f2a18fc2)

Answer (score 0):

The below webpack configuration (in ES6) and package.json work. Essentially the package.json needs to contain "type":"module" indicating the target is ES6. The webpack configuration then needs to export an javascript object whose properties are configuration keys and the values as appropriate. Below is an example:

```
"use strict"
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
    mode: "development", 
    entry: ["./src/lib-junk.jsx"],
    experiments: {outputModule: true},
    output: {
        filename: "lib-junk-dist.js",
        clean: true,
        library: {type: "module"}
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options:{
                    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
                },
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            }
                ]
  
                    },
                    externalsType: 'module',
                    externals: {
                        'react': 'react',
                        'react-dom/client': 'react-dom/client',
  
                    },
                    plugins: []
                }
```

The equivalent CommonJS is as below:

```
  "use strict"
   const webpack = require('webpack');
    module.exports = {

  mode: "development",

  entry: ["./src/lib-junk.jsx"],

  //Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289200/output-an-es-module-using-webpack
  experiments: {outputModule: true},

  output: {
  
    filename: "lib-junk-dist.js",
    
    clean: true,

    //Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289200/output-an-es-module-using-webpack
    library: {type: "module"}
  },

  devtool: "source-map",

  module: {
  
    rules:[
        {
            test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            //options: babelrc,
            options:{
                        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
                    },
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
        }
    ]
  
  },

    externalsType: 'module',
    externals: {
  
      'react': 'react',
      'react-dom/client': 'react-dom/client',
  
    },

  plugins: []
  
}
```

The dependencies for the above in package.json is as below

```
"files":["components/*","*.mjs"],
    "main":"index.js",
    "type":"module", //This is essential for ES6
    "scripts": {

        "build": "webpack --config build/webpack.config.dev.js"

    },
  
    "dependencies": {
    
        

    },
    
     "peerDependencies": {

        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
    
    },
    
    "devDependencies":{
    
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0", 
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.1",
        "webpack": "^5.1.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
        "url-loader":"^4.1.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.0.0"
    
    }
```

NOTE: In my case I am using Babel to transpile .jsx files only, it is not required for webpack to use this config, far I could figure.

Answer (score -3):

Edit: Works as of Feb 2021

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/pull/2381

---

You can't. You have to convert it to CommonJS, either with `babel` or `esm`.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/282

But you can run `webpack -r esm @babel/register`