# Why does the es6 version of my webpack config give me an error, but the es5 version doesn't?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm working on bundling a project using webpack, and I'm doing so with this config that is compiled with babel 6 (node 5, npm 3):

```
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
  entry: './node_modules/graphql/graphql.js',
  output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: "var",
    library: "graphql"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  devtool: 'eval'
};
```

However, with babel 6, this gives me an error when I run `webpack`:

`Output filename not configured.`

If I translate this code back to es5:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './node_modules/graphql/graphql.js',
  output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: "var",
    library: "graphql"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  devtool: 'eval'
};
```

it works just fine.

My `.babelrc` file looks like this:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

and I have the following packages installed in the local node_modules:

```
├── babel@6.0.15
├── babel-core@6.1.2
├── babel-loader@6.0.1
├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.1.3
├── babel-runtime@6.0.14
├── graphql@0.4.12
└── webpack@1.12.3
```

**EDIT**
Upon further inspection of the code Babel spits out, I think my problem is the `export default` isn't getting properly transpiled to `modules.export`:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _webpack = require('webpack');

var _webpack2 = _interopRequireDefault(_webpack);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

exports.default = {
  entry: './node_modules/graphql/graphql.js',
  output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: "amd",
    library: "graphql"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  devtool: 'eval'
};
```

How do I get Babel to properly transpile es6 module code to Node's module format with the `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin?

Comment: check out my other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549895/i-cant-use-es6-in-webpack-config-file . This may work if you just want to be able to trans-pile the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this capability has been deprecated from Babel.

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2212