# Output an ES module using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2, es6-modules

With Rollup I can output an ES module by simply setting the `format` option to `'es'`. How can I do the same with webpack? If it's not possible now, does webpack have any plans to add it?

The only thing I've found in the [documentation for `output.libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget) that mentions ES modules is this:

> `libraryTarget: "commonjs-module"` - Expose it using the `module.exports` object (`output.library` is ignored), `__esModule` is defined (it's threaded as ES2015 Module in interop mode)

However, it's rather unclear to me. Is it the same as `libraryTarget: "commonjs2"` with the only difference that `__esModule` is defined? What is "interop mode"?

Comment: FYI, the relevant ticket on webpack: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933

Comment: In ~3 months, its going to be 2022, the ticket is still open, that too since 2016! Might have to move to **rollup**!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Webpack2 does not have relevant libraryTarget yet, it does not output ES6 bundles. From the other side If you bundle your library in CommonJS bundlers wont be able to run Tree Shaking, not being able to eliminate unused modules. That's due to ES modules are still developing, so nobody ships ES bundles to browser, while webpack used primarily to create browser enabled bundles.

From the other side if you are publishing library you can provide both CommonJS (umd) and ES targets, thanks to ["module" key in package. json](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es6-modules.md#51-determining-if-source-is-an-es-module).  Actually you do not need webpack to publish ES target, all you need to do is to run babel on every file to get it to es2015 standart, for example if you are using react you can run babel with just "react" preset. If your source is already ES 2015 without extra features you can point module straight to your src/index.js:

```
//package.json
...
  "module": "src/index.js"
  "main": "dist/your/library/bundle.js
...
```

I found it convenient to use babel to handle `export v from 'mod'` instructions in my main index.js, so I have 1 module file exporting all my modules. That's achieved with babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions (also included in stage-1 preset).

I spot this approach from react-bootstrap library, you can see scripts in their github (they are webpack1). I have improved their scripts a little in my [react-sigma repo](https://github.com/dunnock/react-sigma), feel free to copy following files which will do what you need:

```
config/babel.config.js
scripts/buildBabel.js
scripts/es/build.js
scripts/build.js // this is command line controller, if you need just ES you don't need it
```

Also look at lib target (scripts/lib/build.js and .babelrc), I provide lib transpiled modules so library users can include only modules they need even without ES explicitly specifying require("react-sigma/lib/Sigma/"), especially useful if your lib is heavy and modular!

Comment: The problem I found with importing `src/index.js` directly is that it it doesn't work if the original source is importing images, sass, etc since your loaders in webpack.config will normally exclude `node_modules` for these file types.

Comment: node_modules excluded from babel-loader, since libraries shipped already transpiled we don't need babel there. If source needs to import images or other assets config should be extended with appropriate loader, for instance file-loader or sass-loader with settings to include node_modules if needed. Ref images or css good practice is to copy all static content to your application static folder.

Comment: The downside of that is that if you’re building a component library or similar type of module that imports other assets, every application that uses your module has to be configured with all the appropriate loaders. It adds a lot of cruft to the app’s Webpack config, plus it’s brittle since the library might only be compatible with specific versions of plugins/loaders. It would be nice to use webpack without bundling/converting to CJS while still transforming non-JS modules into importable equivalents when building the library

Answer (score 34):

Firstly I would like to state the difference between the `commonJS` and `commonJS2`

`CommonJS` doesn't support the use of `module.exports = function() {}` which is used by `node.js` and many other `commonJS` implementations.

*`Webpack2` employs the concept of the bundling the library code and for the widespread use of it and to make it compatible of working in different environments we use the --[libraryTarget](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#add-librarytarget) option*

Now the part here will answer both your questions

The possible library options supported in `webpack2` are

- `libraryTarget: "umd", // enum`
- `libraryTarget: "umd-module", // ES2015 module wrapped in UMD`
- `libraryTarget: "commonjs-module", // ES2015 module wrapped in CommonJS`
- `libraryTarget: "commonjs2", // exported with module.exports`
- `libraryTarget: "commonjs", // exported as properties to exports`
- `libraryTarget: "amd", // defined with AMD defined method`
- `libraryTarget: "this", // property set on this`
- `libraryTarget: "var", // variable defined in root scope`

**Interlop** has the following meaning

> In order to encourage the use of **CommonJS** and **ES6 modules**, when exporting a `default export` with no other `exports` `module.exports` will be set in addition to `exports["default"]` as shown in the following example

```
export default test;
exports["default"] = test;
module.exports = exports["default"];
```

So basically it means that the `commonJS-module` can be used by *exposing* it as `module.exports` by using the `interloping` with *ES2015 module wrapped in commonJS*

More info about the `interloping` can be found in this [blogpost](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/misunderstanding-es6-modules-upgrading-babel-tears-and-a-solution-ad2d5ab93ce0#.okohqovy3) and the stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default) to it.

The basic idea is in `ES6` *runtime export and import properties cannot be changed* but in `commonJS` **this works fine** as the *require changes happen at runtime* therefore it has **ES2015** is **interloped** with the **commonJS**.

**Update**

**Webpack 2** *gives the option of creating the library which can be bundled and included*.

If you want your module to be used in different environments *then you can bundle it as a library by adding the library options and output it to your specific environment*. Procedure mentioned in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/).

Another simple example on how to use commonjs-module

Important point to note here is `babel` adds `exports.__esModule = true` to each `es6 module` and on importing it calls for the `_interopRequire` to check that property.

`__esModule = true` need to be set only on *library export*. It need to be set on the `exports` of the *entry module*. *Inner modules* don't need `__esModule`, it's just a babel hack.

As mentioned in the docs

> `__esModule` is defined (it's threaded as **ES2015** Module in **interop** mode)

Usage as mentioned in the [test cases](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/66edde657eda2344954700feb1c9ae6e376d7fdc)

```
export * from "./a";
export default "default-value";
export var b = "b";

import d from "library";
import { a, b } from "library";
```

Comment: Could you answer my main question: is it possible to output an ES module using webpack? Also, how does `commonjs-module` work with named exports?

Comment: if you dont understand what i have written in the update,then the answer is yes - by adding the library option,and named exports test case as mentioned above.

Comment: `commonjs-module` and `commonjs2` are [apparently equivalent at this point](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3559#issuecomment-268965473), with the former possibly being deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

### What is the best non-hacky solution?

<s>Apparently, [this feature is coming in Webpack 5](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933#issuecomment-652942095)</s>

<s>Update: Webpack 5 was released, but [still doesn't support this behavior](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933#issuecomment-715643176).</s>

<s>Update 2: See [this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933#issuecomment-774253975) which makes it seem like it is coming soon.</s>

Update 3: [The newest version of Webpack should support this use case !](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933#issuecomment-920316860) (Although it seems the implementation is still a bit buggy.

If you need to use older versions of Webpack you can use the steps described in [this](https://paultavares.wordpress.com/2018/07/02/webpack-how-to-generate-an-es-module-bundle/) blog post to use a plugin which can allow for outputting an ES module.

When using the blog post above (the post's example code is a little off) we first run

```
npm i -D @purtuga/esm-webpack-plugin
```

We can then set `webpack.config.js` to the following:

```js
const EsmWebpackPlugin = require("@purtuga/esm-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "consoleUtils.js",
        library: "LIB",
        libraryTarget: "var"
    },
    //...
    plugins: [
        new EsmWebpackPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Then we can just use the file like normal.

```js
import func from "./bundle.js";

func();
```

See also [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933) which is tracking this feature.

Comment: Considering this feature is not supported currently by Webpack, all solutions will be always hacky. The only difference with your proposal is that the hacky approach is taken by the plugin instead of being taken directly by you.

Comment: @colxi Of course the real solution by the plugin is hacky, but **we don't have to deal with anything hacky**. This is especially easy for beginners, since it is a very small modification.

Answer (score 14):

With the latest Webpack V5 (as of September 2022), you can do this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.ts"],


  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },

  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist/myOutputFile.mjs`,
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
  },
};
```

I also set `devtool: false` and used `externals` to keep things like React out of the bundle.

See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933 and https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytype for more details.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind adding an additional file to your package , you can use this workaround as a solution that allows you to **distribute/import Webpack bundles as ES6 modules**:

### Configuration

webpack.config.js

```js
output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: '__MODULE_DEFAULT_EXPORT__',
    libraryTarget: 'window',
    libraryExport: 'default'
  },
```

./dist/index.js (we need to create this file)

```js
import './bundle.js'
const __MODULE_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = window.__MODULE_DEFAULT_EXPORT__
delete window.__MODULE_DEFAULT_EXPORT__
export default __MODULE_DEFAULT_EXPORT__
```

package.json (important if you are going to distribute your module)

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
```

### How it works :

- Webpack outputs the bundle to `/dist/bundle.js`, using the `window` as `libraryTarget` method. According to my configuration, this makes the package **default export** available as `window.__MODULE_DEFAULT_EXPORT__`, as soon as it's imported.
- We create a custom "loader" :  `./dist/index.js`, which imports the `/dist/bundle.js` , picks the `window.__MODULE_DEFAULT_EXPORT__` , deletes it from the `window` object (cleanup), assigns it to a local variable, and exports it as a ES6 export.
- We configure our `package.json` to point to our "loader" : `./dist/index.js`
- We can now perform a regular `import MyDefaultExportName from './dist/index.js'`

> Note : This solution -as it is exposed here- is far from being perfect, and has some downsides and limitations. Although there is space for improvements :)

Comment: This worked great for. It's mind-boggling that webpack still does not have an option for packaging as modules.

Comment: if running in node, I guess there will be an error `window is not defined`

Comment: @xianshenglu for Node you can replace  `window`   with  `global`