# Prevent Babel-loader/webpack to transpile es6-modules to es5

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

```js
module.exports = {
  bail: true,
  watch: true,
  target: 'web',
  entry: paths.allLibraryIndexJs,
  output: {
    path: paths.appLibraryBuild,
    filename: '[name].app.js',
    library: '[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  externals: {
    lodash: {
      commonjs: 'lodash',
      commonjs2: 'lodash',
      amd: 'lodash',
      root: '_'
    },
    react: {
      commonjs: 'react',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
      root: 'React'
    },
    'props-types': {
      commonjs: 'props-types',
      commonjs2: 'props-types',
      amd: 'props-types',
      root: 'PropsTypes'
    },
    'react-dom': {
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom',
      root: 'ReactDOM'
    },
    redux: {
      commonjs: 'redux',
      commonjs2: 'redux',
      amd: 'redux',
      root: 'redux'
    },
    moment: {
      commonjs: 'moment',
      commonjs2: 'moment',
      amd: 'moment',
      root: 'moment'
    },
    'semantic-ui-react': {
      commonjs: 'semantic-ui-react',
      commonjs2: 'semantic-ui-react',
      amd: 'semantic-ui-react',
      root: 'semantic-ui-react'
    },
    'react-redux': {
      commonjs: 'react-redux',
      commonjs2: 'react-redux',
      amd: 'react-redux',
      root: 'react-redux'
    },
    'react-i18next': {
      commonjs: 'react-i18next',
      commonjs2: 'react-i18next',
      amd: 'react-i18next',
      root: 'react-i18next'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      paths.appSrc,
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', 'svg', 'ttf', 'woff', 'eot', '.scss'],
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web'
    }
  },

  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter
            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader')
          }
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc
      },
      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.svg$/
        ],
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
      //{
      //  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      //  include: paths.appSrc,
      //  loader: 'babel-loader',
      //  options: {
      //    compact: true
      //  }
      //},
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(Object.assign({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                minimize: true
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                plugins: () => [
                  require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: [
                      '>1%',
                      'last 4 versions',
                      'Firefox ESR',
                      'not ie < 9' // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                    ],
                    flexbox: 'no-2009'
                  })
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        extractTextPluginOptions
      ))
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 50000,
          mimetype: 'application/font',
          name: './fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    //   inject: true,
    //   template: paths.appHtml,
    //   minify: {
    //     removeComments: true,
    //     collapseWhitespace: true,
    //     removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    //     useShortDoctype: true,
    //     removeEmptyAttributes: true,
    //     removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    //     keepClosingSlash: true,
    //     minifyJS: true,
    //     minifyCSS: true,
    //     minifyURLs: true
    //   }
    // }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        screw_ie8: true, // React doesn't support IE8
        warnings: false
      },
      mangle: {
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        screw_ie8: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin(cssFilename)
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
}
```

I am using webpack to bundle a library. I am developing it in es6 as a part of another project where it gets transpiled to es5 using a separate webpack config. I want to bundle it as a library/es6 module using webpack/babel-loader, but not able to find a way to prevent babel-loader to transpile it es5. If I don't use babel-loader, it throws me 'module parse failed' error.

I tried looking for a solution in documentation and StackOverflow, but couldn't find it. Please help.
I am attaching my current webpack config.

Comment: I think your question is similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289200/output-an-es-module-using-webpack

Comment: Can you share your `.babelrc`

Comment: what do you mean by prevent es5 transpilation ? do you want one file or multiple one (keep `import` or not, support commonjs loading ?). Webpack has support for `import` declaration and will convert them into require calls, but some of the features that you are using may not be supported, are you sure you are only using valid es6 and no "stage-x" features ? Your babelrc would help.

Comment: I don't have any specific .babelrc for the project but in my  `package.json` i specify 
```"presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]```
I would prefer it to be one single file and not to imported as a folder.

Comment: no, I won't possible. webpack is transpiler. its transpile to es5 and it's use nodejs. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Why not distribute the module as it then and let the other project do bundling and transpiling

Comment: That's what I want. But want it bundled in es6.