# How do you make a library truly tree-shakable with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tree-shaking

I have a library of multiple react components, and I want to make the library tree-shakable so that when I import a component like

```
import { Checkbox } from 'my-react-components'
```

I don't import the whole bundle.

My index.js looks like this

```
export { default as Button } from './components/Button'
export { default as Checkbox } from './components/Checkbox'
export { default as FlexView } from './components/FlexView'
export { default as Radio } from './components/Radio'
export { default as Select } from './components/Select'
export { default as TextInput } from './components/TextInput'
export { default as Toggle } from './components/Toggle'
```

And I bundle using webpack

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./lib'),
    filename: 'react-components.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },

  // loaders and stuff...
  // terser-webpack-plugin...

  externals: {
    // don't include react in the bundle
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: false,
    sideEffects: false,
  },
}
```

And in my babel config of course I have

```
['@babel/preset-env', {
  modules: false,
}]
```

With this setup when I import only one component, and the whole bundle gets included (I am using webpack also when I import it). How do I prevent this?

Comment: Are you building as production when importing them?

Comment: Yes, I am building in production mode

Comment: Does this help? https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free

Answer (score 3):

As of February 2020 it is not possible with Webpack.

Because tree-shaking mechanism heavily relies on ES6 `import/export` and Webpack currently doesn't support ES2015 module format in `output.libraryTarget`.

As an alternative you can bundle your library with other bundlers like Rollup (which does support ES6 modules for libraries).

You can keep track of this feature here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933

**UPDATE**:
Though there is hacky workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010871/921193

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working by directly importing the file from the library's lib folder, instead of just naming the library by itself.

in my case, I imported some of the components from Reactstrap library like this:

```
import Button from 'reactstrap/lib/Button';
import UncontrolledPopover from 'reactstrap/lib/UncontrolledPopover';
import PopoverHeader from 'reactstrap/lib/PopoverHeader';
import PopoverBody from 'reactstrap/lib/PopoverBody';
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also need the `module` property on your `package.json`

```
{
   ...
   "main": "lib/index.js",
   "module": "lib/index.esm.js",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an effective [babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-imports) to help transform your import according to the rules you specified.

```
[
   'transform-imports', // or 'babel-plugin-transform-imports'
   {
     'react-router': {
       transform: 'react-router-dom/${member}',
       preventFullImport: true
     },
     reactstrap: {
       transform: 'reactstrap/lib/${member}',
       preventFullImport: true
     }
   }
]
```

Note: 
`preventFullImport` is useful if you want to make sure your import to that path is tree-shakeable.

---

This is just another way of implementation to help you effectively tree-shake unused import. But importing directly per file would be the best practice in the long run.

```
import Button from 'reactstrap/lib/Button';
import UncontrolledPopover from 'reactstrap/lib/UncontrolledPopover';
```