# Unable to import webpack-bundled UMD library as an ES6 import

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, module

I've authored a javascript library using Webpack. The entrypoint `someClass.js` looks like this:

```
import x from './x'
/* several more imports here */

class SomeClass {}

export default SomeClass;
```

My webpack config that bundles this library is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './someClass.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'lib.js',
        library: 'lib',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
```

I then import the generated `lib.js` into a simple `index.html` that is defined as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In `app.js`, I simply try to import the file as follows:

```
import  * as lib from './lib.js';

console.log(lib);

// Output: Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}   Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
```

However, this import statement does not seem to work as planned (I expect a module with a `default` field that is my `SomeClass` constructor).

The only way I can access my library's default export `SomeClass` is if I do a global import statement in `app.js` as follows, which sets `lib` as an object on `window`:

```
import './lib.js';
console.log(window.lib);

// Output: Module {default: ƒ, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"} default: class SomeClass_SomeClass
```

I don't want my class to available at the global `window`, as it makes it tough to modularise my code.

I also want to be able to use this library in a variety of places on the web (react app, standalone html files, etc), and so want to minimize dependencies.

Is there anything I can do to import the module as an es6 import?

Answer (score 0):

The ES6 [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) works only with the `export` keyword like:

```
export { A }
export default B
```

Nodejs's commonjs2 module will not work on the Web, which looks like:

```
module.exports = { A, default: B }
```

Webpack's `libraryTarget: "umd"` output will not keep the ES6 `export` keyword either,
for reason that the keyword syntax is not ployfill-able and will break on other environment.

So you may want to release with 2 set of files like other packages do (`cjs/` and `es/`), and use babel or rollup to pack the `es/` version and keep the ES6 `export` keyword.

Also check out: [Output an ES module using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289200/output-an-es-module-using-webpack) which explains the Webpack part really well.

Answer (score 0):

There is one default class exported:

`import SomeClass from './lib'` therefore should work?

Otherwise we should check the webpack bundle to find out what's happening. I don't think there is a use case for `* as` at all.

ECMAScript is supported since Node.js 13.2.0. So I vote for transpiling to ES6 & upgrade Node.js if ancient.

Since [async & defer](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/script-tags-do-they-belong-in-the-body-or-the-head-section-be5733e38347) it's recommended again to put `<script>` into `<head>`.