# TypeScript module system config vs Webpack library type

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack, ts-loader

I'm working on my first TypeScript library (it's actually even my first JavaScript library) which is used in the front-end. In essence, it should expose a function which receives a DOM element and adds another DOM element to it as a child.

I would like to use Webpack to bundle the library and during configuration of it and TypeScript I stumbled across **module systems**. And they are confusing me.

In `tsconfig.json` I can define which module system should be used in the compiled code, if I understand correctly:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6"
  }
}
```

And in the `webpack.config.js` I am able to set a desired target for my library using `output.library.type`, where I can again specify a module system:

```js
module.exports = {
  output: {
    library: {
      name: 'my-lib',
      type: 'umd',
    }
  },
```

I only need my library to be installable via npm/yarn:

```sh
$ yarn add my-lib
```

And consumable via an an import statement like that:

```js
import { myFunc } from 'my-lib';
```

So far so good, with these settings it seems to do what I want. But I don't understand what I am doing here. Hence the questions: **What is the difference between the two module system configuration options** (the one in the TypeScript config and the one in the Webpack config)? And **what settings are appropriate for my use case**?

Comment: Have you read [Typescript module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) and [Webpack output library type](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytype)?

Comment: @jabaa yes, still confused.

Comment: TypeScript allows `imports` but not all browsers and engines allow you. `compilerOptions.module` describe how the TypeScript files are translated to JavaScript. You can use all [module methods](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/) that are supported by Webpack. After translation, the project is bundled with Webpack and `output.library.type` describes the module loader.

Comment: This question contains helpful information about `output.library.type`: [Output an ES module using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41289200/16540390)

Comment: So do I understand correctly that for my use case, an ES module is what I want?

Comment: Yes, `import { myFunc } from 'my-lib';` is an ES module import.

Comment: That already helps a lot. In your previous comment you mentioned the term "module loader". What is that exactly?

Comment: There was a time some years ago when JavaScript didn't provide functionality to load modules. A module is a package of code that you want to use in your code. People invented different non-standard loaders for modules. Later, a module loader was standardized. The standard module loader is ES modules.

Comment: By _loading_ a module you refer to the process of "injecting" variables and functions from one file into another file?

Comment: I wouldn't formulate it that way, but we're probably speaking about the same.