# Can't use ES6 import in webpack config

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, import, ecmascript-6

CommonJS import `const webpack = require('webpack');` works fine, but ES6 `import webpack from 'webpack';` no.

From [Webpack Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#es6-recommended-):

> Version 2 of webpack supports ES6 module syntax natively.

But it doesn't work out of the box for me.

I'm also tried:

- use `babel-loader` for JS files;
- add "babel" to the config files names.

But it's all doesn't work.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.dev.babel"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
}
```

**webpack.config.common.babel.js**

```
export const /* in this implied like default */ module = {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: '/node_modules/'
        }
    ],
};
```

**webpack.config.dev.babel.js**

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import commonConfig from './webpack.config.common.babel';

export default merge(commonConfig, {
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ]
});
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

And when i type `npm run build:dev` it's throws:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

**Questions:**

1. How to make ES6 import work?
2. It is possible out of the box, i.e. without any `babel-loader` packages?

Comment: Does it work if you rename your config file to just `webpack.config.babel.js`?

Comment: You also need to install `babel-preset-es2015`, `babel-loader` isn't enough.

Comment: @laggingreflex it doesn't work, if i rename to `webpack.config.babel.js`. I just installed these modules: `"babel-cli", "babel-core", "babel-loader", "babel-preset-env", "babel-preset-es2015"` and set `"presets": ["es2015", "env"]`, but still not working.

Comment: I think you use babel-preset-env *instead* of babel-preset-es2015, but I'm don't think that's causing your problem.

Comment: @Kevin i tried use these things separately. It doesn't work.

Comment: See these threads: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1403#issuecomment-136333170 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js/31906902#31906902

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use ES6 in webpack.config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js

Comment: @laggingreflex I tried to use all of these methods and wrote about some here. And I looked these resources before and none of this solved my problem. It seems much easier to use CommonJS...

Comment: https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#babel-and-jsx I think your missing `npm:babel-register`

Answer (score 0):

For any users that stumble upon this post 2023, Webpack 5 now supports ES6 natively.

To enable ES6 imports in webpack.config.js, add the

"type": "module",

option at the main level of your package.json file configuration.

Answer (score -10):

Well, the first thing I notice is that you can't use "import" in your webpack file. You need "require":

```
  const webpack = require('webpack');
```

You cannot use import because that is ES6, and how can you use ES6 if you haven't installed babel yet? No JS engine (afaik) natively supports ES6, and definitely not Node.

Also, I think you're going to get a warning for the ES2015 - I think it should be "babel-preset-env" now.

Comment: I pointed on the Webpack Documentation: "Version 2 of webpack supports ES6 module syntax natively." >natively.

Almost full quote: "Version 2 of webpack supports ES6 module syntax natively, meaning you can use import and export without a tool like babel to handle this for you." >you can use import without a tool.

Comment: Yes, but does that mean that you can do it always, or *once* webpack is installed, *only* with the files with which webpack is dealing? I think it's the latter. How is webpack going to help Node deal with ES6 if webpack isn't loaded yet? It's a chicken and egg thing. You have to use ES5 in the webpack config files. For your apps source files, it's fine.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand a little, but webpack is loaded and he dealing with the files. I mean, webpack handles the files, not Node. Even if so, as you said, then I already tried babel-loader for handling ES6 files. It doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, but when that import is called, webpack isn't running yet. Webpack can't handle instantiating itself. A pen can't write on itself. I'm certainly no expert here, but this just makes logical sense. Webpack can't be transpiling ES6 before webpack is up and running. Just think through the process here.

Comment: You can use `import` if you name your file `webpack.config.babel.js`; webpack will run babel on the config file.

Comment: @Kevin i understood you. But I saw that others use ES6 import in webpack config files.

Comment: Cool. According to @laggingreflex it can be done. I never bothered. I'm not sure what the advantage is, other than people think ES6 is "cooler".

Comment: @Kevin No, it doesn't work. The advantage is that it is modern (relative to CommonJS). Why we should use old technologies instead new one? It's irrational.

Comment: I love ES6. It has a lot of nice features. But for something simple like setting up a config file, I don't see the need.

Comment: You can use ES6 like this boilerplate: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap