# Requires Babel "7.0.0-0" but was loaded with "6.26.3"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

Keep getting this error no matter what I tried installing (babel wise) as I follow other similar reports. this is the stack trace:

> ```
> error: bundling failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was
> loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of
> @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is
> loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to
> look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or
> "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset:
> "C:\\Users\\Admin-ESS\\Absent\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
>     at throwVersionError (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:65:11)
>     at Object.assertVersion (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:13:11)
>     at _default (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:150:7)
>     at C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
>     at C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:317:46
>     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
>     at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
>     at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
>     at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
>     at OptionManager.init (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
>     at File.initOptions (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
>     at new File (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
>     at Pipeline.transform (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
>     at Object.transform (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\src\transformer.js:135:5)
>     at Object.transformCode [as transform] (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker\index.js:253:15)
>     at execMethod (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\jest-worker\build\child.js:92:29)
>     at process.on (C:\Users\Admin-ESS\Absent\node_modules\jest-worker\build\child.js:42:7)
>     at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
>     at emit (internal/child_process.js:783:12)
> ```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Absent",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "jail-monkey": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.22.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.3.8",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated here...

Comment: It didn't work for me, but multiple people reported success with the [`babel-upgrade`](https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade) tool.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looks like you need to install `babel-core` as the docs suggest:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel

`yarn add --dev babel-jest babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0 @babel/core regenerator-runtime`

Comment: tried using babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0 and it worked. thanks for the prompt reply :)

Comment: Issue is not fixed for me with this :(

Comment: Lovely solution.

Answer (score 64):

Test which version you are running with cmd

```
babel -V
```

If it is not verion 7 or higher

```
npm uninstall babel-cli -g
npm uninstall babel-core -g
```

And

```
npm install @babel/cli -g
npm install @babel/core -g
```

If you are using Jest run

```
npm install babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0 --save-dev
```

> Uninstall and reinstall @babel/node solves the problem if you do node development.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall @babel/node worked for me, thanks

Comment: Solved my issue too. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks!
This solved my issue. I need to do the installation and uninstallation step locally in my repository as well!

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 26):

Sometimes its because you have installed both **babel-cli and babel/cli**, or **babel-core and @babel/core**
It causes conflicts

So

1) delete node_modules

2) remove babel-cli, babel-core from your package.json, keep @babel/core, @babel/cli

3) npm install

**babel-cli** conflicts with **@babel/cli**

**bable-core** conflicts with **@babel/core**

Comment: Solved my issue too. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

For the ones who still fighting that, 4 days ago Jest v24 released with native support for babel 7. enjoy.

Comment: Thank you!. For me, this meant to remove the `require('babel-register')` and `require('@babel/polyfill/noConflict')` from my `globalSetup` file.

Comment: Upgrading to Jest v24 worked for me, without need for `babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0` (which actually did not work). Having tried both, I feel like this should be the accepted answer in 2019.

Answer (score 8):

None of the solutions I found online worked, I fixed it the following way:

1. Remove `jest` and `@babel/core` from package.json (keep `babel-core` v7 bridge)
2. Remove node_modules and package-lock.json
3. npm install
4. npm install jest @babel/core --save-dev

Answer (score 3):

From the Babel Docs, I found that there is an issue with the order in which you install the deps.

> Note: Please install @babel/cli and @babel/core first before npx babel, otherwise npx will install out-of-dated babel 6.x.

As per the usage [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#usage). I found that removing both items from `package.json` and adding them in order, fixed my issue. Bizarre edge case.

Answer (score 3):

you need this 4 packages, that will fix the issue:

```
 npm install @babel/cli
 npm install @babel/core
 npm install @babel/node
 npm install @babel/preset-env
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the issue was caused by upgrading my `@babel/core` version, while I kept an outdated `webpack` (and/or `webpack-cli`, I simply treated them identically in batch) version. I happened to be using a Webpack config file that was `webpack.config.babel.js`. Webpack seems to deal with this internally by using `babel-register` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31906902/12109043)). This was evidenced by my require stack:

```
at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/me/Projects/github-wide-mode/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at compile (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
    at loader (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
                                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    at require (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:6)
```

So `webpack-cli` was calling `babel-register` – whose version I presume was dictated by the outdated version of `webpack-cli` – causing it to target an older version of `@babel/babel-core` than I had installed.

### The solution

I uninstalled the `webpack` and `webpack-cli` packages, deleted my `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json`, and then did a fresh `npm install`.

If this doesn't immediately work, I would suggest following the suggestion included in the error:

> Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.

to pinpoint what is causing (what is most likely) the dependency mismatch. I would also recommend deleting entries in your `package.json`'s `dependencies` (and/or `devDependencies`) and then reinstalling them at the npm defaulted version, until they play nice with each other. Stripping away non-essential dependencies and resetting default dependencies should eventually work.

Comment: As a side note for anyone else who happens to be dep-upgrading an antique package setup that uses `webpack.config.babel.js`: `babel-register` seems to have been included with older versions of `webpack` or `webpack-cli`, but is dropped in more recent version. This causes `webpack-cli` to complain of 'Unable to use specified module loaders for ".babel.js".' Simply install `@babel/register` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The issue on my side was a conflict between `babel-core`, imported by `babel-register`, and `@babel/core`, required by Babel documentation for latest usage and set as root npm dependency

It seems `babel-register` has been moved to `@babel/register`. Babel didn't update docs with the new module name although they did for their cli/core packages

Here is an update of [setup babel doc](https://babeljs.io/en/setup#installation) that works for me:

Installation

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/register
```

Usage

In your package.json file make the following changes:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/register"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT recommended to install babel globally. It might be that your IDE has recognized your globally installed package and is going based off of that one. Or what is more likely is that you have have packages that conflict with each other. e.g babel-cli conflicts with @babel/cli

> While you can install Babel CLI globally on your machine, it's much better to install it locally project by project.

```
yarn remove global @babel/cli @babel/core
```

In project directory...

```
yarn remove babel-cli 
yarn add @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/node --dev
```

Comment: The issue for me was that I was installing babel-core. Instead I needed @babel/core

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally had a file called `.babelrc` in my root directory with the following contents:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

After I deleted that file, I no longer got this error when running my `gulp` command.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you have a local version, so remove it so that the global version is ran:

```
npm uninstall babel-cli
npm uninstall babel-core
```

Answer (score 0):

- Delete node modules.
- Update your devdepdencies to

```
"devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
      "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
      ........
}
```

- npm install

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `npm ls babel-core`?

[image]

This was mine, so I removed `babel-cli@6.26.0` and `babel-register@6.26.0` from `package.json`, and installed `@babel/cli` and `@babel/register`

**It might be a good idea to delete your lock file and rebuild it.**

Answer (score -2):

1. Delete `node_modules`
2. Update devDependencies to:

```
"devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
      "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
}
```

3. Install npm again:
   `npm install`

Comment: This is a **duplicate** answer, thus subject to deletion (RE answer by KushalSeth). Welcome to SO. There are some unique rules for the SO platform that you may not be aware of: Useful answers should be upvoted, NOT duplicated for SO to work as intended. It is a different format from forums. You can read more at StackOverflow.com/help.