# react native bundling failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3"

Tags: react-native, babel-core

I get an error when using Expo in my react native app. When importing the following line of code. (Only part of my code where I use the import 'expo')

```
import {Permissions, ImagePicker} from 'expo';
```

I get an error. I'm all day searching for a solution. I think its because of the version of React I use is updated? I tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873516/requires-babel-7-0-0-0-but-was-loaded-with-6-26-3), but it didn't work and got even more errors. Also removed node_modules folder and reinstalled it, but nothing seems to work.

When installing `yarn add babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0` the app crashed (Objects are not valid as a React Child". And in debug mode it also doesn't work.

There are also some yarn check errors. When installing the missing dependencies, I even get more errors.

> bundling failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-preset-expo\index.js")
>       at throwVersionError (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules@babel\plugin-proposal-decorators\node_modules@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:65:11)
>       at Object.assertVersion (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules@babel\plugin-proposal-decorators\node_modules@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:13:11)
>       at _default (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules@babel\plugin-proposal-decorators\lib\index.js:35:7)
>       at E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules@babel\plugin-proposal-decorators\node_modules@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
>       at Function.memoisePluginContainer (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:113:13)
>       at Function.normalisePlugin (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:146:32)
>       at E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:184:30
>       at Array.map ()
>       at Function.normalisePlugins (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:158:20)
>       at OptionManager.mergeOptions (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:234:36)
>       at E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:265:14
>       at E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:323:22
>       at Array.map ()
>       at OptionManager.resolvePresets (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
>       at OptionManager.mergePresets (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
>       at OptionManager.mergeOptions (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
>       at OptionManager.init (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
>       at File.initOptions (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
>       at new File (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
>       at Pipeline.transform (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
>       at Object.transform (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\metro\src\transformer.js:135:5)
>       at Object.transformCode [as transform] (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker\index.js:253:15)
>       at execMethod (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\jest-worker\build\child.js:92:29)
>       at process.on (E:\stack\Github\turfMeister\testProject\node_modules\jest-worker\build\child.js:42:7)

whole component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
    View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image,TouchableOpacity,Alert
} from "react-native";
import {Avatar, Divider, Header} from "react-native-elements";
import {auth, database} from "../config/config";
import {Permissions, ImagePicker} from 'expo'; //enabling this line gives an error



class GlobalAccount extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

        user_code: "Chen",
        user_object: null,
        user_avatar: null,
        user_first_name: null,
        user_last_name: null,
        user_email: null,

        imageID: this.uniqueId(),

    };

    alert(this.uniqueId());
    this.findNewImage();

}

s4 = () => {

    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
};

uniqueId = () => {
    return this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + "-"
        + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4();
};

_checkPermissiosn = async () => {
    const { statusCamera } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({cameraPermission: statusCamera});

    const { statusCameraRoll } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    this.setState({cameraPermission: statusCameraRoll});



};

findNewImage = async () => {
    this._checkPermissiosn();

};




/**
 * Testing purpose only.
 */
alertElement(){
    Alert.alert(
        "Change your profile photo?",
        "",
        [
            {text: "no"},
            {text: "yes"}
        ]
    )
}

/**
 * Before mounting the scene, load the data
 */
componentWillMount(){
    this.loadDataFromDatabase();
}


/**
 * When pressed, logout the user.
 */
signUserOut = () => {
    var that = this;

    auth.signOut()
        .then(console.log("user is signed out"))
        .catch((error) => console.log("error occured while signing user out: ", error));

    that.setState({
        loggedin: false
    })
};


/**
 * Download the data from the server.
 * Only data corresponding to the user.
 */
loadDataFromDatabase = () => {
    this.setState({
        refresh: true,
        groups: [],
    });

    var that = this;

    // exampleUser must be the user who is logged in.
    database.ref('Users').child(this.state.user_code).once("value")
        .then(function (snapshot) {
            const exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);

            if (exists) {
                var user_object = snapshot.val();

                console.log("user_object is : " , user_object.avatar);
                console.log("user name is " + user_object.firstName);

                that.setState({
                    user_object: user_object,
                    user_avatar: user_object.avatar,
                    user_first_name: user_object.firstName,
                    user_last_name: user_object.lastName,
                    user_email: user_object.email,
                });

            }
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
};


/**
 * Render the 'my account' page.
 * @returns {*the account page.*}
 */
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.imageView}
                onLongPress={()=>{this.alertElement()}}
            >

                <Image style={styles.image}
                       source={({uri: this.state.user_avatar})}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View>
                <Text> Username: {this.state.user_first_name} {this.state.user_code} </Text>

                <Text> Email: {this.state.user_email} </Text>
                <Text>City: </Text>
            </View>
            <View>


                <Button
                    title={"Logout"}
                    onPress={() => this.signUserOut()}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
}

//TODO move this to the styleSheet package.
export default GlobalAccount;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
imageView :{
    height:100,
    width:100,
},
image: {


    flex:1,
}

});
```

Package.json file

```
 {
  "name": "testProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^31.0.6",
    "expo-font": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.483",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.0.2410"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

yarn check says

> yarn check v1.9.2
>   info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
>   info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
>   error "react-native#react@16.3.1" doesn't satisfy found match of "react@16.6.3"
>   error "expo#expo-react-native-adapter#react-native@^0.57.1" doesn't satisfy found match of "react-native@0.55.4"
>   error "expo#react-native-reanimated#react@16.0.0-alpha.6" doesn't satisfy found match of "react@16.6.3"
>   error "expo#react-native-reanimated#react-native@^0.44.1" doesn't satisfy found match of "react-native@0.55.4"
>   warning "jest-cli#jest-message-util#@babel/code-frame@^7.0.0-beta.35" could be deduped from "7.0.0-rc.2" to "@babel\code-frame@7.0.0-rc.2"
>   error "babel-preset-expo#metro-react-native-babel-preset#@babel/core@*" doesn't satisfy found match of "@babel\core@7.0.0-rc.2"
>   error "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators#@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin##@babel/core@^7.0.0" doesn't satisfy found match of "@babel\core@7.0.0-rc.2"
>   error Found 6 errors.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being down for more than half a month I found the problem. Somehow I dont actually used (the correct) Expo!? Here is how I fixed it. My solution can be some cumbersome, I think there is a faster solution, but it works.

> You can check if your app uses expo by doing the following: yarn start. If in the command line there is **not** an QR code, you **dont** use (*the correct*) Expo.

How to solve?

1. install npm create-react-native-app
2. Create a new project by create-react-native-app [name of the app]
   at step 2 it went wrong with me, because this version actually creates a combination of react-native and Expo. and I used something else apparently
   (You can chose the example app with  or not without react-navigation. This choise doesnt matther.)
3. cd [name of the app] and then yarn start.
   Make sure you see in the command line a QR code. Else it does **not** use *the correct* expo.
4. I now coppied my old project into this new one. (you also can copy the newly made files into your old one, but I got problems doing so, since all kind of expo dependencies at my old project where wrong.
5. (not mandatory) Download on the target device the Expo app ([android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=en_US)). The expo app can open your app with the QR code. (tested it only with android)

If you know how to solve this problem faster/without copying the whole project to a new one, I'd like to hear from you.