# Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3" - @babel/preset-env

Tags: babeljs, babel-preset-env

I get the following error the moment I install @babel/preset-env and try running a node.js file.

```
Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3"
```

Following is the stack trace

```
(While processing preset: "P:\\Projects\\ReactNative\\apc-c\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
    at throwVersionError (P:\Projects\ReactNative\apc-c\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:65:11)
    at Object.assertVersion (P:\Projects\ReactNative\apc-c\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:13:11)
    at _default (P:\Projects\ReactNative\apc-c\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:154:7)
    at P:\Projects\ReactNative\apc-c\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
    at P:\Projects\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:317:46
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I have tried a number of this from installing "7.0.0-bridge.0", etc.

Can someone please help. Have spent hours trying to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requires Babel "7.0.0-0" but was loaded with "6.26.3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873516/requires-babel-7-0-0-0-but-was-loaded-with-6-26-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem. I had a .babelrc file that contained a reference to @babel/preset-env and transform-react-jsx. Removed them and the js file compiled just fine.

Comment: Wow, that was a needle in a haystack and solved my problem perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help. Been facing same issue (though not React-native just React) and just got to fix it now, can I see what your package json looks like? Maybe you can update your question with it. 
Also what script command produces this error?

Comment: Thanks Vanassa, I have asked a follow up question with all the required details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157519/unable-to-run-a-node-js-file-with-babel-preset-env Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could install global babel-cli, you can try the command

```
npm uninstall -g babel-cli babel-node
```

you need to install @babel/cli and @babel/node.
OR
you can uninstall node and remove the npm file in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming`

I hope I can help you. good luck