# Unable to run a node.js file with @babel/preset-env

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I'm trying to run a simple node.js file which needs the @babel/preset-env preset. The moment I run the js file, I get a message saying

Requires Babel “7.0.0-0” but was loaded with “6.26.3”

To replicate the issue, please try the following in a new folder:
1. Run the following commands

```
npm init
npm install @babel/register
npm install @babel/core@^7.2.2
npm install @babel/preset-env
```

2. Create a .babelrc file with the following

> ```
> {
> "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
> "plugins": []
> }
> ```

3. Create a sample emp.jsx with the following

> ```
> import React from "react";
> class CommentBox extends React.Component {}
> ```

4. Create a parse.js file with the following

> ```
> require('babel-register')({presets: ['env', 'react']});
> let Emp = require('./emp.jsx');
> ```

Now run the parse.js file by running

> ```
> node parse.js
> ```

You should see the error mentioned above. I have been trying to fix with for a long time now. Please help.

Many Thanks

Comment: you should install and use `@babel/register` instead

Comment: Thanks @WilliamChong. Tried that, but no luck. I still get the same error. When do you suggest I install @babel/register? I installed it after installing @babel/core@^7.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The .babelrc file that contained a reference to @babel/preset-env. Removed it and the js file compiled just fine.

Answer (score 1):

followed your instructions  and using @babel/register instead with 
this package.json run with no issues

```
tasted on
node : v8.11.2
yarn : 1.12.3
```

paese.json

```
require('@babel/register')({});
let Emp = require('./emp.jsx');
console.log(Emp)
```

packge.json

```
{
  "name": "sof",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Naor, doesn't work for me. This is the batch file I'm running

call npm init
call npm install @babel/register
call npm install @babel/core@^7.2.2
call npm install @babel/preset-env
node parse.js

Get the same error. Also have made a small edit to the parse.js file above. Please have a look.