# How solve problem with install vue native?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-native

When I install vue native. I get this Err.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51IXq.jpg)
 I cant understand what I need to do.
I find some link about babel [Requires Babel "7.0.0-0" but was loaded with "6.26.3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873516/requires-babel-7-0-0-0-but-was-loaded-with-6-26-3)
install and it doesnt work.

Comment: it's happen when I execute command vue-native init

Answer (score 0):

I solve it, when I move in my created project, and make command `npx babel-upgrade`.
It's strange, because I was upgraded babel globaly erly