# Can't resolve this issue: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm developing a CLI with NodeJS. I use Nodemon for development. So when I do `npm run start` (= `nodemon --exec babel-node bin/main.js`), everything works fine. However, when I install my CLI (with `npm i -g .`) and run it (with `opews` (name of my CLI)), I get this error:

```js
Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "/Users/arthurfontaine/Documents/Lab/opews/parser/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
```

---

Here's part of my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "dom-parser": "^0.1.6",
    "franc": "^5.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.2.2",
    "lda": "^0.2.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-vibrant": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node bin/main.js"
  }
```

and my `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

and the header of my `main.js`:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env babel-node

'use strict';
```

---

What I tried:

- globally uninstall `@babel/cli` to see if it didn't load the globally installed one instead of the project one
- uninstall / reinstall "Babel-related" modules in my project with `npm i @babel/cli @babel/node @babel/core @babel/preset-env --save-dev`
- install `babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0` like it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873516/requires-babel-7-0-0-0-but-was-loaded-with-6-26-3)
- install `babel-core` but it install the `6.23.3` version

Every time I try, it gives me the same error

What I checked:

- if `6.23.3` appears in my `package-lock.json` but not
- run `npx npm-why @babel/helpers` as it says at [this issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8482). it returns me:

```
Who required @babel/helpers:
opews > @babel/core > @babel/helpers@7.10.4
```