# SyntaxError using spread operator in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

In my webpack.config.js i am importing several JS objects for the configuration from other files.
These object are composed using spread operator.
Ex. in build.js

```
const otherObj = { a:[], b: [] }
const conf = {
  prop1: [],
  ...otherObj
}
```

Then i want to use these objects in the webpack.config.js in this way:

```
const { prop1, a, b } = require('./build.js');
module.exports = {
    entry: { prop1, a, b },
    rules: [
      {
        test: jsRegex,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
    ]
}
```

When i launch the build script i get a SyntaxError:

```
    ...otherObj,
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

NOTE: Here follows the .babelrc

```
    {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/syntax-object-rest-spread"
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the version of `node` that you are using. For example, using node `v6.15.1` (Boron) will return the same error you have, but when running on `v8.14.0` (Carbon) it compiles just fine.

### Use node

Check that the node version you are using supports the features you need.

The feature you are using [object spread properties](https://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties) was added on `v8.6.0` (running node without flags).

### Use babel

You can [transpile your webpack config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31906902/220272), this way you can use your current node version and use all the ES6 features you may like.

Comment: Thank you @a--m! just updated Node to 8.12.0 and it's working fine now.

Comment: Great! Keep an eye on what features are supported, since support on `node` is still partial.

Answer (score 0):

You should add .babelrc file like this below.

Then do install:   `npm i babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]

}
```

This is worked for Me, try it!