# How to get an object (that uses esnext syntax) from webpack config in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, webpack.config.js

What I'm trying to achieve is to use dynamically created object in webpack config in a typescript script project (that uses **esnext** module syntax like *import*, *export*, dynamic *import()*)

i.e. something like below (in DefinePlugin)

File - webpack.config.js

```
const productA = require("./<path>/ProductA");
const productB = require("./<path>/ProductB");
let product;

switch(process.env.PRODUCT_TYPE) {
  case 'ProductA':
    product = new ProductA();
    break;
  case 'ProductB':
    product = new ProductB();
    break;
  default:
    console.log("ERROR - Incorrect product type")
    process.exit(-1);
 }
...
...
{
  entry: './src/entry.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader'
    }]
  },
  ...
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        productType: () => {
            return product;
        }
    })
  ]
}
```

Script - DynamicLoad.ts

```
let product = productType();
product.run();
```

But, the problem I'm having is with esnext syntax types i.e. ProductA and ProductB classes here uses esnext syntax like *import*, *export* and *implements* keywords. So, *webpack* throws error when imported these classes into the *webpack.config.js* files.

**So, is there a way to make *webpack.config.js* understand the *esnext* syntax?**

---

**Different workarounds tried and failed**

1. Use babel

babel supports *imports*, *export* and dynamic *import()* syntax. So, followed [How can I use ES6 in webpack.config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js#comment102444032_31903692) and tried with babel (i.e. webpack.config.babel.js)

**Issue:** But, with this the errors I faced:

- babel not able to identify *implements* keyword.
- couldn't find .css module (my webpack has css-loader and style-loader)

2. webpack in typescript format

   - Webpack support typescript formatted config i.e. webpack.config.ts
   - Ref - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#root

**Issue:** But, the issue with this is *webpack.config.ts* needs module type of **commonJS** whereas my project uses **esnext**. So, many syntax identification errors are generated.

**So, is there any way for me to achieve this in webpack?**

Comment: When I faced a similar problem (to create a TS class outside of `webpack.config.js` and then import it into this file), I emulated the TS class using a JS function in a separate .js file. Then called the function inside .js to create objects which are effectively instances of the emulated TS class. Those objects where exported from .js file and imported using `require` into `webpack.config.js`. The problem I had after that was that other TS code (which also needed those objects) could not import it. Was solved by creating .d.ts file. Sounds complex but the code is simple. Can provide it here..

Comment: ... if such emulation is acceptable.

Comment: I tried to move the TS class (used in webpack config) to JS. But the issue I had is the converted JS class still imports other class those are in typescript format. So, getting errors on those imported class.