# Understanding basic webpack with es6 modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am starting to familiarize with javascript development. I want to use modern syntax and use webpack. But I still quite don't understand how this works.

When I run `npx webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js` I get this error:

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This is my minimal reproducible example:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mre2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

config.babel.js

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

index.js

```
console.log('hello world')
```

webpack.config.babel.js

```
import path from 'path';

export default {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js'
    ]
  }
};
```

When I add `"type": "module"` to my package.json, I get this other error

```
Must use import to load ES Module: /home/liliam/Alejo/mre2/webpack.babel.config.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /home/liliam/Alejo/mre2/webpack.babel.config.js from /home/liliam/Alejo/mre2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename webpack.babel.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /home/liliam/Alejo/mre2/package.json.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51774289/2581562

Comment: I was missing @babel/register and babel-loader packages. I figured this out thanks to the accepted answer in the link you provided. Thank you