# ESM import on webpackConfig

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, config

I'm building a webpack app and I'm interested in use ESM through the entire app, meaning that build the webpack.config file with ESM imports.

I now this is possible using Babel, but this was before npm added the `"type": "module"` supporting now ESM imports without babel... I already tried it with Express and it worked but with Webpack I get this:

```
> ...proyectDirectory/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93

> require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

So I was wondering if there is a version of webpack-cli that use `import` instead of `require`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use ES6 in webpack.config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js)

Comment: No, it doesn't - Babel is the ancient way of use ES6 in node.js, now node supports ESM but seems that some libraries have not adapted this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to at least webpack-cli 4.5.0. Support for native ESM configuration files has just been added: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/releases/tag/webpack-cli%404.5.0

This means that if you're using `webpack.config.js` in a directory with `{"type": "module"}` in its package.json, it will work.

It will also work if you simply name your file `webpack.config.mjs`

Comment: Just make sure the file you import have the `.js` after, it did not work for me till I did that

Answer (score 1):

Webpack CLI is expecting a commonJS file. There is experimental support for `.mjs` file that can be enabled using the `experiments.mjs` flag but it seems there are a number of issues around that. So you can use webpack by using either no config or using a `.cjs` config as:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli --config webpack.config.cjs
```

Also keep in mind that things like Jest do not work with esm (as of this date) so you'd need to use another test suite if no babel/esm was desired.