Webpack's ambiguous relationship with ES6 modules
Does Webpack support ES6 modules natively or not? This is a simple question but its answer seems to be more complicated than I initially thought.

On one hand, Webpack allows you to use ES6 syntax when importing modules in your JS code. In fact, this is the recommended way to deal with modular code in your projects. Just take a look at the documentation:


On the other hand, however, Webpack's own configuration file seems to not be able to handle ES6 natively. Take a look at this StackOverflow question, for instance:



And its accepted and highest-voted answer:

Really, Webpack? You natively support and even recommend using ES6 modules for people's code, but your own config file doesn't allow it? You need me to install a plugin just for handling your own config file? Come on. That's so contrary to my experience with you so far.
Not only for aesthetical reasons, though. The other day I was trying to test some of my functions using Node, so I imported one of my modules from Node's REPL, and it told me since the module was using ES6-style imports and exports, I needed to include "type":"module" in package.json. Which I did, but then Webpack stopped working because webpack.config.js was not using ES6.
So I had to remove that "type":"module" from package.json. Now I'm planning to do some unit testing of my code and I'm trying to figure out what the best route is now.
Why, Webpack. Why.

Those are two very different contexts, one is running in Node when you do your build, and one is the actual files being processed to generate the output bundle, so it's not really that surprising that they'd have different implementation details.

"You natively support and even recommend using ES6 modules for people's code, but your own config file doesn't allow it? " - your understanding is correct. Unless Webpack uses Webpack to bundle config file (it's not bundled, so no), there's no reason to assume these things are connected. They aren't. I'm voting to close because ranting is not constructive. You're referring extremely outdated questions for some reason The answer is yes https://stackoverflow.com/a/66296243/3731501

Thank you for this info, @EstusFlask. Your comment is a testament to the fact that ranting sometimes is constructive.

As Estus Flask points out in their excellent comment to my question, Webpack does indeed natively support ES6 modules. They just don't use it in their documentation examples.
Here are some tips to update your Webpack configuration file to ES6:
On package.json:

Add "type":"module" in package.json

On webpack.config.js:

Change CommonJS module syntax into ES6:

const foo = require("foo"); becomes import foo from "foo";
module.exports = bar; becomes export default bar;

If you were using __dirname, now you have to import it with

const __dirname = import.meta.dirname;
That's it. That worked for me. Sorry for the rant.

None of the above has anything to do with webpack. What you are saying is Node.js support ES6 modules with the given changes. Obviously webpack is written in node but none of this has anything to do with webpack per se. It's just how to configure node.js to do what you want. Alternatively you can also rename your config file as webpack.config.mjs without changing package.json

Hello @slebetman, thanks for the feedback. I updated my answer to more clearly specify what files I am talking about because clearly you got confused. Also, you seem a bit sour. Is everything OK?
