# Webpack 5 and ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I think I've read every thread on SO and every related page on the internet on this, everything has some variation of a problem

I want:

- To use webpack to bundle my web app up
- To use ES Modules within my source js and have them transpiled down for wider browser support
- To use ES Modules within my webpack configuration

Node 14 allegedly supports ESM, so lets use that

**Setup 1**

I have `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`

then my `webpack.config.js` looks something like:

```
import { somethingUseful } from './src/js/useful-things.js';

export default (env, argv) => {
    return {
        // webpack config here
    };
}
```

running `> webpack` (webpack-cli) I get:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\git\Useroo\webpack.config.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of webpack.config.js from C:\nvm\v14.14.0\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\groups\resolveConfig.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename webpack.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from package.json.
```

OK, so lets do what the error message says

**Setup 2a**

If I remove `"type": "module"` from my `package.json` I get

```
webpack.config.js
import { somethingUseful } from './src/js/useful-things.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

right.... So lets try the other suggested alternative:

**Setup 2b**

```
module.exports = async (env, argv) => {

    var somethingUseful = await import('./src/js/useful-things.js');

    return {
        // webpack config here
    };
}
```

I get a segfault.

`/c/Program Files/nodejs/webpack: line 14: 14272 Segmentation fault      "$basedir/node" "$basedir/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" "$@"`

Comment: You're running `webpack` through `webpack-cli` code which is not ESM as far as I know, I guess that might be why you can't use ESM in `webpack.config.js`. You should be able to make the first two points with webpack.

Comment: @chenxsan is there an alternative way I can invoke webpack then?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/ecma-script-modules/

Comment: @OmerCohen what am I looking at here? Which part solves my problem?

Comment: Why not just use CommonJS in your `webpack.config.js` file? Seems like you're trying to use ESM code from your `src` in webpack configuration. If you must use it, maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js for help.

Comment: not a solution, because even if he used commonjs in his webpack.config.js file, he may require a module that imports an ES module, so the same error will come again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing, webpack-cli just doesn't support ES6 modules, so you basically have to re-implement it yourself.

It's not that hard really, just annoying. You need something like this (simplified for brevity): Just RTFM here https://webpack.js.org/api/node/

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.js';


var config = await webpackConfig(mode);
var compiler = webpack(config);

compiler.watch()
```

Comment: how would this file be called as opposed to the default webpack?

Answer (score 16):

`webpack-cli` now supports ES Modules. All that is required is

- adding `"type": "module"` to your package.json

*or*

- name your webpack config with the `mjs` extension: `webpack.config.mjs`

Answer (score 1):

Webpack does not have native support for ESM config files, as the other answer states, but it does support automatically transpiling them.  If your config file is named `webpack(.whatever).babel.js`, and you have `babel` properly installed, your config file will be quietly downleveled before use.

As far as I know, the only way to configure Babel in this case is to use a top level `.babelrc` in your project directory.  Mine simply contains `{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]}`.  It does mean that if I want to use Babel in the build, I have to configure it through e.g. plugin options, but it works for me.

ETA: user @bendwarn says in a deleted comment that [as of Webpack CLI 4.5.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/releases/tag/webpack-cli%404.5.0) you can name your config file `webpack.config.mjs` or just call it `webpack.config.js` if your package is `type: "module"` and it should work natively.  I haven't tried it (and frankly that second one sounds like a terrible idea).