# Use Webpack 5 to build an ES module bundle, and consume that bundle in a Node.js ES module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, es6-modules, webpack-5

Is it possible to use Webpack 5 to build an ES module bundle (with a default export), and then consume (import) that bundle in a Node.js ES module?

- Here's a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-nofjl9-zxxgir?file=README.md&terminal=) of the following files.

I've got the following files:

```
|- webpack.config.js
|- package.json
|- /src
  |- index.js
```

**`index.js`**

```
function util() {
    return "I'm a util!";
}
export default util;
```

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
};
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "exporter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  }
}
```

After running `npm run build`, we get:

```
|- webpack.config.js
|- package.json
|- /src
  |- index.js
|- /dist
  |- bundle.js
```

Great, now I want to just create some "demo" file `importer.js` which would import `util` and use it. For convenience, I'll create it on the same folder:

```
|- importer.js
|- webpack.config.js
|- package.json
|- /src
  |- index.js
|- /dist
  |- bundle.js
```

**`importer.js`**

```
import util from './dist/bundle.js';

console.log(util());
```

Now I run `node importer.js`, and I get this (expected) error:

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
[...]
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Ok then, let's add that `"type": "module"` to `package.json`:

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "exporter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Now, trying again `node importer.js` get us another error:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module './dist/bundle.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

What's more, when trying to re-run `npm run build`, we get yet another error:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'path\to\webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

- Note: [Webpack 5 and ESM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944796/webpack-5-and-esm) might be considered as somewhat related, but really it isn't, as it wants to use `webpack.config.js` *itself* as an ES module.

How can I make it work?

Comment: what version of webpack and webpack-cli are you running?  they're not listed in your `package.json`.

Comment: I ask because with `webpack@^5.51.1` and `webpack-cli@^4.8.0` I end up with an empty `bundle.js` file when I attempt to build.

Comment: @DanO, that's the result indeed, I'm with those versions as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you use `type: "module"`, Node.js will treat this module as ESM. From the doc [esm_no_require_exports_or_module_exports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_or_module_exports), `require`, `module.exports`, `__dirname` are not avaliable in ESM. I will use ESM syntax to rewrite `webpack.config.js`.

Create a polyfill for `__dirname` variable.

From webpack documentation:

> If you're using webpack to compile a library to be consumed by others, make sure to set `output.libraryTarget` to 'module' when `output.module` is `true`.

E.g.

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

export default {
  mode: "development",     
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
};
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "exporter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

`./src/index.js`:

```js
function util() {
  return "I'm a util!";
}
export default util;
```

`importer.js`:

```js
import util from "./dist/bundle.js";

console.log(util());
```

Build:

```sh
⚡  npm run build   

> exporter@1.0.0 build /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/webpack-samples/packages/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/68913996
> webpack

asset bundle.js 3.01 KiB [compared for emit] [javascript module] (name: main)
runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules
./src/index.js 65 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.51.1 compiled successfully in 87 ms
```

Execute `importer.js`:

```js
⚡  node importer.js 
I'm a util!
```

Comment: I think you have a small mistake in the `package.json`: Shouldn't it be either `"main": "dist/bundle.js"` or `"module": "src/index.js"`, as detailed [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#final-steps)?

Comment: Also, maybe you'll be able to shed a light on my [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68929190/import-npm-linked-es6-local-package-by-its-package-name-works-when-using-main).

Comment: you mentioned that you should use `output.libraryTarget` but you didn't use it in your example snippet