# Why importing from a linked local ES modules package using the package name works with "main" property but fails with "module"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules, npm-link

**Question**

Why does importing from a linked local NPM pacakage (built as an ES module) using the pacakge name works when the `pacakge.json` has the `"main"` property, but fails when it has the `"module"` property?

**Setup**

More spicifically, if we have the following setup:

1. `exporter`: A Node.js package which is an ES module that `export`s something (e.g., using `export default`).
2. `importer`: A Node.js module that tries to `import` what `exporter` exports, using `import something from 'exporter'`.
3. Using `npm link` to locally link `exporter` to `importer`.

Then:

- The setup runs successfully if `exporter`'s `package.json` uses the `main` property.
- The setup run **fails** if `exporter`'s `package.json` uses the `module` property.

  - This failure can be "fixed" by using `import something from 'exporter/dist/bundle.js'`, *but that's unacceptable*.

**Why is that?** I guess I'm doing something wrong?

- For some more info about this setup, see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913996/use-webpack-5-to-build-an-es-module-bundle-and-consume-that-bundle-in-a-node-js)

**Code**

**`exporter`**

```
|- webpack.config.js
|- package.json
|- /src
  |- index.js
|- /dist
  |- bundle.js
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

export default {
  mode: "development",     
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
};
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "exporter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js", <-- *** NOTE THIS LINE ***
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

`index.js`:

```js
function util() {
  return "I'm a util!";
}
export default util;
```

**`importer`**

```
|- package.json
|- /src
  |- index.js
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "importer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module"
}
```

`index.js`

```js
import util from 'exporter';

console.log(util());
```

Then:

1. Linking:

```sh
⚡  cd exporter
⚡  npm link
⚡  cd importer
⚡  npm link exporter
```

2. Executing:

```sh
⚡  node importer.js 
I'm a util!
```

**However**, if `exporter`'s `package.json` is changed to:

```json
{
  "name": "exporter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "module": "dist/bundle.js", <-- *** NOTE THIS LINE ***
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Then:

2. Executing:

```sh
⚡  node importer.js
```

Fails:

```sh
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'importer\node_modules\exporter\' imported from importer\src\index.js
```

But Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When resolving a node_modules package, Node.js first checks if there's a `"exports"` field in the `package.json`, if there's none it looks for a `"main"` field, and if it's. also not there, it checks if there's a file named `index.js` – although this behavior is deprecated and may be removed in a later version of Node.js, I would advise against relying on it and always specify `"exports"` and/or `"main"` fields. You can check out [Package entry points](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points) section of Node.js docs to get more info on that.

`"module"` is simply not a field Node.js uses, it's used by some other tools so it's certainly okay to have it defined in your `package.json`, but you should also have `"main"` and/or `"exports"` fields. Node.js will use the file extension to determine if the file is an ES module (`dist/bundle.js` is using `.js` as extension and you have `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`, so you're all set).