# Why i'm getting this Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module despite of installing webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

Hi i'm getting this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

**Expection:** i'm ready to use any library or npm package if it solves the just `import` problem , any extension file not just `.vue` only

despite of installing webpack `"webpack": "^5.73.0"`

Here is how my **project structure** will look like

```
/project_folder
  package.json
  index.js
  webpack.config.js
  components/
             HelloWorld.vue
```

**package.json**

```
 {
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
};
```

**index.js**

```
 import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

 console.log(HelloWorld);
```

**Note:** this type of project structure design is required for our plugin component, project structure design cannot be changed.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/ecma-script-modules/) helps? In short: add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`.

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Use Webpack 5 to build an ES module bundle, and consume that bundle in a Node.js ES module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913996/use-webpack-5-to-build-an-es-module-bundle-and-consume-that-bundle-in-a-node-js)

Comment: @MauriceNino add same error after adding too  (ran `$npm rebuild`). so i will edit my question with this addition.