# React and Webpack: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs, babel-loader, es6-modules

I'm trying to rewrite my Webpack (5.42.0) `webpack.config.js` from using **require()** (CommonJS) to using **import from** (ESM). But whenever I try to load my page, I'm getting:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Module../some/path/file.js (login.bundle.js:10731)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../some/path/util.js (login.bundle.js:10564)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../some/path/module/Module.jsx (OtherFile.jsx:37)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6)
```

I cannot figure out what causes this error. There are a lot of moving parts in the Webpack setup, but I'm guessing the reason `require` is not added to the bundle may be because of a Babel config issue?

I'm using hot module replacement, various plugins (Terser etc.). Excerpts from `package.json` and `webpack.config.js` are added below. I think all relevant lines are included:

```js
// package.json excerpt:
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
}
```

```js
// webpack.config.js excerpt:
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin from '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin';
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';

const config = () => {
  return {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'],
            plugins: ['react-refresh/babel'],
          },
          resolve: {
            fullySpecified: false,
          }
        },
      ],
    },
    entry: {
      main: [
        `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3500/`,
        './app/App.jsx',
      ],
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name]/[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'backend/path/bundles'),
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:3500/',
    },
    // …etc…
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question: [How can I use ES6 in webpack.config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js) ?

Long story short, webpack.config.js is parsed with Node, which doesn't supports es6 by default. You may rename your config file `webpack.config.babel.js` though.

This being said, using import syntax is of little importance in such a file, `require` looks good to me.